# Understanding L2-norm output for 3D tensor - TensorFlow2

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow2.x

For Python 3.8 and TensorFlow 2.5, I have a 3-D tensor of shape (3, 3, 3) where the goal is to compute the L2-norm for each of the three (3, 3) square matrices. The code that I came up with is:

```
a = tf.random.normal(shape = (3, 3, 3))

a.shape
# TensorShape([3, 3, 3])

a.numpy()
'''
array([[[-0.30071023,  0.9958398 , -0.77897555],
        [-1.4251901 ,  0.8463568 , -0.6138699 ],
        [ 0.23176959, -2.1303613 ,  0.01905925]],

       [[-1.0487134 , -0.36724553, -1.0881581 ],
        [-0.12025198,  0.20973174, -2.1444907 ],
        [ 1.4264063 , -1.5857363 ,  0.31582597]],

       [[ 0.8316077 , -0.7645084 ,  1.5271858 ],
        [-0.95836663, -1.868056  , -0.04956183],
        [-0.16384012, -0.18928945,  1.04647   ]]], dtype=float32)
'''
```

I am using axis = 2 since the 3rd axis should contain three 3x3 square matrices. The output I get is:

```
tf.math.reduce_euclidean_norm(input_tensor = a, axis = 2).numpy()
'''
array([[1.299587 , 1.7675754, 2.1430166],
       [1.5552354, 2.158075 , 2.15614  ],
       [1.8995634, 2.1001325, 1.0759989]], dtype=float32)
'''
```

How are these values computed? The formula for computing L2-norm is [this](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/L2-Norm.html). What am I missing?

Also, I was expecting three L2-norm values, one for each of the three (3, 3) matrices. The code I have to achieve this is:

```
tf.math.reduce_euclidean_norm(a[0]).numpy()
# 3.0668826

tf.math.reduce_euclidean_norm(a[1]).numpy()
# 3.4241767

tf.math.reduce_euclidean_norm(a[2]).numpy()
# 3.0293021
```

Is there any better way to get this without having to explicitly refer to each indices of tensor 'a'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The formula you linked for computing the L2 norm looks correct. What you have is basically this:

```
np.sqrt(np.sum((a[0]**2)))
# 3.0668826

np.sqrt(np.sum((a[1]**2)))
# 3.4241767

np.sqrt(np.sum((a[2]**2)))
# 3.0293021
```

This can be vectorized by the following:

```
np.sqrt(np.sum(a**2, axis=(1,2)))
```

Output:

```
array([3.0668826, 3.4241767, 3.0293021], dtype=float32)
```

Which is effectively the same as using `np.lingalg.norm` (or `tf.math.reduce_euclidean_norm` if you want to use tensorflow)

```
np.linalg.norm(a, ord=None, axis=(1,2))
```

Output:

```
array([3.0668826, 3.4241767, 3.0293021], dtype=float32)
```

The default keyword `ord=None` is for calculating the L2 norm per the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html). The `axis` keyword is to specify which dimensions we want to reduce which should be clear from the first code snippet.